# How can i validate a pattern in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, model

I have the following model . I want *cartaoCidadao* to follow a pattern of a 8 numbers String (example:12345678) and that *estado* can only take two possible values(infetado and suspeito) . How can I make that validation?

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  cartaoCidadao: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    index: {
      unique: true,
    },
  },
  password: { type: String ,required:true},
  role: { type: String },
  estado:{type:String}
});
```

Comment: Which package are you using, mongoose?

Comment: @terrymorse yes,mongoose

Answer (score 1):

There are a few built-in validators in [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#built-in-validators).

So for `estado`, which  can only have two possible values ('infetado' and 'suspeito') you could use an `enum`:

```js
estado:{
  type:String;
  /* enum validator */
  enum: ['infetado', 'suspeito']
}
```

And for `cartaoCidadao`, a string with exactly 8 numeric digits, you could use `match`:

```js
cartaoCidadao: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
  index: {
    unique: true,
  },
  /* match (RegExp) validator */
  match: /[0-9]{8}/
}
```

Comment: thanks. I searched and found this. Do you recommend it?
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-input-validation-simple-and-clean-in-your-express-js-app-ea9b5ff5a8a7/